# print preview is truncated in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, firefox, printing

Printing is defective in Firefox as of recently on my Ubuntu 20.04 with Firefox 90. HPLIP is installed.

I need to print .HTML files previously saved by Firefox. In both `print > save to PDF` and `print > LaserJet P2015` the right side of the print preview page is truncated. It is more truncated in the case of a physical printer; less truncated when printing to PDF but still truncated. The preview is accurate in that the hardcopy will also be truncated.

This previously worked as little as 1 month ago.

I have updated Ubuntu and I have reinstalled Firefox but that does not resolve the problem. Resetting the Firefox printer settings does not resolve the problem. Installing HPLIP does not resolve the problem. Opera does not see the printer; it offers only the ability to print to a file. "Ubuntu Software" does not offer Chrome. "Ubuntu Software" offers Chromium but it will not install it.

What is the correct way of printing?

Edit: Firefox on Windows 10 has the same problem. I printed it successfully with Edge on Windows 10.

Comment: This seems to be [Bug 1720621](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1720621) affecting FF 90+. Also [Bug 1720719](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1720719). For me, 18.04, regular printing also affected. Rolling back to FF89 may be the only solution for now.

Comment: [90.0.2](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/90.0.2/releasenotes/) has been released that supposedly fixes this issue. For Ubuntu, hopefully it shows up in Software Update soon.